# What's the best way to obtain patch from mailing archive?

Tags: git, archive, patch

I was browsing through the QEMU-devel mailing archive, and discover a patch I would like to try out.

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2013-11/msg01543.html

What is the best way to to obtain this patch, so I can do git apply <*.patch>?

Currently, I'm wget the patch in raw format, rename it, and apply it, but it is rather cumbersome.

Comment: Copy and paste from your web browser into a text editor?

Comment: @GavinSmith I image someone already created a small utility to fetch the patch from the mailing archive and name the patch according to the patch title :)

Comment: Maybe you can try `git am` instead of `git apply`?

Comment: @Drunix The problem is that I did not subscribe to QEMU-devel, so I don't have mbox or maildir. Even if I subscribe today, I won't get the old message to my mbox :(

Comment: Yes, but git am takes care of stripping the boilerplate and extracting patch name.